# How to obtain 2-d list from the list but shape defined in another list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

For example I have the `list` like:

```
a = [143, 146, 152, 235, 246, 468, 476, 607, 615, 707, 712]
```

I want to change it to 2-d `list` in this form:

```
b = [
    [143, 146, 152],
    [235, 246],
    [468, 476],
    [607, 615],
    [707, 712]
]
```

or:

```
"143 146 152 
235 246
468 476
607 615
707 712"
```

but from the `list` with shape `= [3, 2, 2, 2, 2]`

How to achieve this one?
I have something like this:

```
devu = ''
for i in b:
    for j in range(i):
        devu += str(b[j])

devu += ' '
print(devu)
```

But got the result as:

```
143146152 143146 143146 143146 143146
```

Comment: Are they grouped by `0-99, 100-199, 200-299` ?

Comment: you can change the line inside of your loop to `devu+=' '+str(b[j])`?

Comment: no,grouping should be done by shape define in the list like i have mention above :[3,2,2,2,2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one approach. Using `iter` and a simple iteration.

**Demo:**

```
a=[143, 146, 152, 235, 246, 468, 476, 607, 615, 707, 712]
a = iter(a)
shape =[3,2,2,2,2]

result = []
for s in shape:
    temp = []
    for i in range(s):
        temp.append(next(a))
    result.append(temp)
print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
[[143, 146, 152], [235, 246], [468, 476], [607, 615], [707, 712]]
```

Comment: Not sure if we should use an of iterator here, and the inner for loop is unnecessary

Answer (score 3):

In case you are working with a data science stack (e.g. `pandas`)

```
>>> pd.Series(a).groupby(np.repeat(np.arange(len(s)),s)).agg(list).tolist()

[[143, 146, 152], [235, 246], [468, 476], [607, 615], [707, 712]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a=[143, 146, 152, 235, 246, 468, 476, 607, 615, 707, 712]
shape=[3,2,2,2]
b=[ [] for item in shape] # creates empty lists in b
idx=0
for item in a:
   b[idx].append(item) # appending the next item
   shape[idx]-=1
   if b[idx]==0:
       idx+=1           
print(b)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can actually iterate over the `groups` list, using the indexes while iterating over it to get slices, and then create your result array

```
a=[143, 146, 152, 235, 246, 468, 476, 607, 615, 707, 712]

groups = [3,2,2,2,2]

res = []

idx=0
#Iterate over groups, and calculate indexes for slicing
for group in groups:
    res.append(a[idx:idx+group])
    #Increment indexes accordingly
    idx+=group

print(res)
```

The output is

```
[[143, 146, 152], [235, 246], [468, 476], [607, 615], [707, 712]]
```

Comment: Hi @SurajGhale I saw you accepted and then unaccepted my answer. Please let me know if something was unclear in the answer and I can clarify it for you :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using `numpy`:

```
import numpy as np
a = [143, 146, 152, 235, 246, 468, 476, 607, 615, 707, 712]
sizes = [3, 2, 2, 2, 2]
assert(sum(sizes) == len(a))
indices = np.cumsum(sizes)[:-1] # Ignore the last size; just take everything that is left (avoids a dangling empty list at the end)
result = [array.tolist() for array in np.split(a, indices)]
# >>> print(result)
# [[143, 146, 152], [235, 246], [468, 476], [607, 615], [707, 712]]
```

One-liner version:

```
result = [array.tolist() for array in np.split(a, np.cumsum(sizes)[:-1])]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use accumulate (from itertools) to compute start and end indexes of sub-ranges to extract:

```
a     = [143, 146, 152, 235, 246, 468, 476, 607, 615, 707, 712]
shape = [3,2,2,2,2]

from itertools import accumulate
b = [ a[s:e] for s,e in zip(accumulate([0]+shape),accumulate(shape)) ]

print(b) # [[143, 146, 152], [235, 246], [468, 476], [607, 615], [707, 712]]
```

You could also do this with reduce from functools (but it would run much slower):

```
from functools import reduce
b = reduce(lambda b,s: b[:-1]+[b[-1][:s],b[-1][s:]], shape, [a])[:len(shape)]
```